# How to return all the rows which has not match in join table and if it had match check the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How to return all the rows of a table `User` when

```
1. a row has not any match with join table ex **UserDetails**
2. a row has a match in **UserDetails**, check some condition ex: user location is **IND**
```

Example table

```
     User
     -----------------------
     id   name
     -----------------------
     1    Hearaman
     2    Ramse
     3    Temmy
     4    Robert

     UserDetails
     -----------------------------
     id   user_id     location
     1    3           USA
     2    4           IND

     Expected results
     --------------------------
     id    name        location
     --------------------------
     1     Hearaman    null
     2     Ramse       null
     4     Robert      IND
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left join` and do the filter

```
select u.id, u.name, ud.location
from User u 
left join UserDetails ud on ud.user_id = u.id 
where ud.user_id is null or 
      ud.location = 'IND';
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for your help.